End date result is not coming after clicking end date in DateRangePicker
In the below code, the filterData is not giving me a proper result, like if I have selected start date as 1 july and end date as a 5 july, in the result i.e. in filterData 5 july data is missing, its only giving result form 1st to 4th.
This is corresponding state declration
const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(new Date());
const [filterList, setFilterList] = React.useState([]);

This is my DateRangePicker in react js
<DateRangePicker
 ranges={[selectionRange]}
 onChange={handleSelect}
 locale={enGB}
/>

And this is handleSelect function for the DateRangePicker
    const handleSelect = (date: any) => {
        const fromdate = date.selection.startDate.getTime()
        const toDate = date.selection.endDate.getTime()
    
        const filterData = accountLogAllDetails?.filter((itemDate: any) => (
        itemDate.dateInMilliseconds >= fromdate && itemDate.dateInMilliseconds <= toDate))
        setFilterList(filterData)
        setEndDate(date.selection.endDate)
        setStartDate(date.selection.startDate)
    }

And in the accountLogAllDetails my response is coming as a
[
  ID: 38372
  actionType:"LOGIN"
  dateInMilliseconds:1720009655000
  userFirstName:"Prakash"
  userId:100077
  userLastName:"rajak"
  userLogin:"prakashRajak@gmail.com.com"
]    

I would be highly grateful if you provide any help in this case.
Tried this solution but it not working
const handleSelect = (date: any) => {
    setStartDate(date.selection.startDate)
    setEndDate(date.selection.endDate)

    const fromdate = date.selection.startDate.getTime()
    const toDate = date.selection.endDate.getTime()


    const startDate1 = new Date(date.selection.endDate);
    const day = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
    const endDate1 = date.selection.endDate.getTime() + day;


    const sday = date.selection.startDate.getTime()
    const eday = new Date(date.selection.endDate)
    const newDay = eday.setDate(eday.getDate() + 1);

    const filterData = accountsLog?.filter((itemDate: any) => {
        // (fromdate < itemDate.dateInMilliseconds) && (itemDate.dateInMilliseconds <= toDate) //end date is making issue
        // (itemDate.dateInMilliseconds >= fromdate) && (itemDate.dateInMilliseconds <= endDate1) //working fine but only today and yesterday is causing issue
        // const item = new Date(itemDate.dateInMilliseconds)
        return itemDate.dateInMilliseconds >= sday && itemDate.dateInMilliseconds <= newDay //only yesterday is causing issue

    })
    setFilterList(filterData)

}
I have Tried the above 3 solution,but none of them working fine, they are causing issue

Please add a link to the NPM date picker library you used.

Can't say for sure without knowing the DateRangePicker library, but it's likely that your end date is e.g. beginning of the day/midnight of July 5th (Fri Jul 05 2024 00:00:00), and  that the item you're expecting to find has a date time of July 5th XX:XX or later. E.g. the difference between midnight UTC and midnight your timezone.

@C.Helling this is the exact problem, but if I'm adding one new day to end date, then the filterData is coming as empty array.

@-codejockie here is the link for the react-date-range-picker https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range
